# Have anybody taken screenshot of BlueStacks running in background successfully like fraps?

Tags: hook, screenshot, bluestacks

I am writing an assist tool for a game running in BlueStacks. I want to take screenshot when BlueStacks running in background(not minimized). Normal GDI ways will get black image. I find it loads ddraw.dll and opengl32.dll, and I successfully hooked these two libraries, but the main entrance functions like glBegin or DirectDrawCreate, DirectDrawCreateEx are not called. So I can not take its back buffer.
But fraps works fine. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

i think you should just take the screen shot the windows way then you later import the file to blue stacks. for those who don't know the combinations to take screen shot is alt+prtsc or windows+prtsc... then you paste it on paint and save it as a .png file

Answer (score 0):

Try using ADB to grab a screenshot. Using a windows screenshot tool does not consider the size of the bluestacks window. Using ADB gives a native resolution screenshot regardless of the size of the bluestacks window. It will even work with the bluestacks window minimized.